# Using Websockets with Django on Google App engine Flex

Tags: django, google-app-engine, redis, django-channels, google-app-engine-python

I'm currently trying to setup a Google app engine flex using a django framework with django-channels. for my current project i need a websocket, so i'm trying to reconstruct the tutorial offered on the website by Django-channels: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/

Currently I'm stuck on adding redis to my google-app-flex instance. I followed the google documentation on setting up a redis connection - unfortunatly the example is in Flask: [google doc](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex) 
I assume my error is trivial, and i just need to connect django CHANNEL_LAYERS to redis proporly.

executing `sudo gcloud redis instances describe <redisname> --region=us-central1` gives me following responce:

Image: "Redis Describtion"
[image: Description Redis]

executing `sudo gcloud app describe`, this responce:

[image: Description App]

I configured my `app.yaml` as follows:

```
# app.yaml
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: daphne django_channels_heroku.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 7

# Update with Redis instance IP and port
env_variables:
  REDISHOST: '<the ip in "host" from "Redis Describtion" image above>'
  REDISPORT: '6379'

# Update with Redis instance network name
network:
  name: default

# [END runtime]
```

..and in my settings.py i added this as the redis connection (which feels really wrong btw):

```
#settings.py
import redis

#settings.py stuff...


#connect to redis
redis_host = os.environ.get('REDISHOST', '127.0.0.1')
redis_port = int(os.environ.get('REDISPORT', 6379))
redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port)

# Channels
ASGI_APPLICATION = "django_channels_heroku.routing.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

what am i doing wrong. how do i connect to Redis using Django correctly?

here are some Links:

https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex

[Django, Redis: Where to put connection-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54534563/django-redis-where-to-put-connection-code)

[Deploying Django channels app on google flex engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662501/deploying-django-channels-app-on-google-flex-engine/59682250#59682250)

[How to connect to Redis instance (memorystore) from Google's Standard App Engine (Python 3.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920339/how-to-connect-to-redis-instance-memorystore-from-googles-standard-app-engine)

https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex

https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/quickstart-gcloud

Comment: Apologies on asking the question here, but were you ever able to get this fully deployed and working? I'm having trouble myself doing a similar setup of Django/Channels/Redis/Flex, and can never get the actual app to start up.

Comment: Awesome detailed question

Comment: @Shane yes i did get is working...sorry didnt see your comment. did you solve it?

Comment: No worries. Indeed I did. I can't recall what my issue was, but all is running fine now.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake is in the settings.py:

Correct version:

```
#settings.py

#settings stuff...

redis_host = os.environ.get('REDISHOST', '127.0.0.1')
redis_port = int(os.environ.get('REDISPORT', 6379))
#redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port)  #this is not needed

# Channels
ASGI_APPLICATION = "django_channels_heroku.routing.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [(redis_host, redis_port)],
        },
    },
}
```